# How to add comments in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I need to add comments to fields in SQL Server, and I know I can do it through designer.

I have many tables where there are the same fields:

- InsertDate
- ModifyDate
- AddUserId
- ModifyUserId

and so on.

I'd like to write a script that will find all tables and will add comments to these fields. Eventually, I can pass tables names to the scripts.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Although I've linked to the duplicate, why wouldn't you *source control* your schema instead and use that for information about *when* and *who* changed things. Especially, scalar `ModifyXxx` properties tend to be pointless because a history of User 1 Creates table, User 2 makes a horrific modification, User 3 makes a benign change ends up pointing at Users 1 and 3 and doesn't give you any clue that you need to hunt down User 2.

Comment: And no one really needs a comment for columns like InsertDate. Don't create pointless work or useless reading.